# How to describe a person pay attention in their lives and know a lot life hacks

Tags: word-choice

In Chinese, we often say you need to be "生活中的有心人“ meaning you need to pay attention to what is happening around you in your daily life, be aware of the changes, surroundings and directions, know a lot of life hacks, and try to make your life better by paying attention.

Comment: Do you mean a person who *does* pay attention,  or a person who *needs to* pay attention but *doesn't*.

Comment: who does pay attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are words like '*savvy*' and '*streetwise*' which mean a person has a lot of 'common sense' - the kind of practical intelligence you learn from real-life experience.

You could describe a person as 'savvy', or advise someone to *be* savvy, which would be like telling them to be aware, observant, smart etc. as they go about daily life.

These are common, but quite informal words. A more formal alternative is '*astute*', but this tends only to be used as an adjective as it is viewed as a personality trait.

Comment: is astute a positive adjective？

Comment: @MER absolutely. To describe someone as 'astute' means *shrewd* or *discerning*. I notice one dictionary lists 'crafty' and 'cunning' as synonyms, and these can have a negative connotation, but 'astute' is considered to be positive.